# Listitem onclick action error in android

Tags: android

I am displaying a list view in android. When I click on each item that particular page should open. So for that I had written the following code.

```
package com.splash;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;

public class Information extends Activity {
    private String[] Countries;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.information);

        Countries = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.countries);

        ListView list = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
        ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row, Countries);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        registerForContextMenu(list);

    }

    protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
        // Get the item that was clicked
Object o = this.getListAdapter().getItem(position);
String keyword = o.toString();
if((keyword.equals("test1"))){




    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),lvereview.class);
       startActivity(intent);
}
else if(keyword.equals("test2")){




 Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.Facebook.com/canadaqbank"));
 startActivity(i);
}
else if(keyword.equals("test3")){




       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),recommendfriend.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
else if(keyword.equals("test3")){




       Intent i = new Intent("android.intent.action.VIEW", Uri.parse("http://www.Facebook.com/canadaqbank"));
       startActivity(i);
    }
else if(keyword.equals("test4")){




       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),ContactUs.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }
else if(keyword.equals("test5")){




       Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),receiveemail.class);
       startActivity(intent);
    }

else
{



    Intent intent=new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Otherapps.class);
      startActivity(intent);
}

//tabView.setCurrentView(R.layout.rowlayout);
//setContentView(tabView.render(2));
}



}
```

Here I have created the list items in strings.xml file. When I m executing this code it is displaying **"The method getListAdapter() is undefined for the type Information"**.What is the problem here...why cant I use that method? Any suggestion will be helpful....

Answer (score 0):

Extend [`ListActivity`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ListActivity.html), not `Activity`.